# How to get a dot over a symbol in gnuplot?

Tags: latex, gnuplot, legend, symbols

I am trying to create a plot in gnuplot with dots over the symbol theta in legend.

I am looking to do something similar to, \dot{\theta} and \ddot{\theta} from latex. However, most posts ask to use 'set term latex' or 'set term epslatex' which outputs a .tex file. I need to keep the output as a pdf with the dot and double dot over the theta in the legend. Is this possible? Appreciate any help. Thanks!

In place of 'Pitch rate', I need the symbol theta with a dot above it. 
In place of 'Pitch acceleration', I need the symbol theta with two dots above it.

```
set term pdf
set termopt enhanced
set encoding utf8
set output "rampfuncs.pdf"
set style func linespoints
set xlabel 'time'
set format y "%.2f"
plot "output.dat" using 1:2 title '{/Symbol q} - Pitch angle', \
"output.dat" using 1:3 title 'Pitch rate', \
"output.dat" using 1:4 title 'Pitch acceleration'
set term x11
```

Update after answer from meuh: Image for reference

[image]

Second update after comments from meuh: Image 2

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is described in the section *Enhanced text mode* of the gnuplot guide. You can use the `~` tilde character to overprint two items, for example `~a/` will overprint `a` and `/`.  In your case you need to raise the dot character by 1.1 times the font size (found empirically) in order for it to appear above the `a` so you prefix the character with this number, and enclose it in braces to make it one item: `~a{1.1.}`

```
plot "data" using 1:2 title '{/Symbol q} angle', \
 "data" using 1:3 title '~{/Symbol q}{1.1.}   rate', \
 "data" using 1:4 title '~{/Symbol q}{1.1..}  accel'
```

which gives this result:

[image]

There seems to be a bug where the title will not be shown correctly if the `~{}{}` construct is at the end of the title. The simple workaround is to add an extra space at the end of the title `~{}{}` .

Comment: Do you see a reason why the legend would be staggered? All I did was replace the plot statement in my code with the following, according to your suggestion.

Comment: plot "output.dat" using 1:2 title '{/Symbol q}', \
"output.dat" using 1:3 title '~{/Symbol q}{1.2.}', \
"output.dat" using 1:4 title '~{/Symbol q}{1.2..}'

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by staggered. By default the text in the legend is right justified. If you want you can select left justification by adding the line `set key Left` (note well the capital letter `L`).

Comment: I've added the image to the question for reference. I also tried adding "set key Left" and the image looks the same.

Comment: I reproduced the same bug. The simple solution seems simply to add a space character at the end of each title, e.g. `'~{/Symbol q}{1.2..} '`

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that bug. `gnuplot -V` says I'm using *gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 3*.

Comment: Thank you! I was on gnuplot 4.6 previously. I have gnuplot 5.2 now and I'm seeing the same behavior you are seeing.

Comment: @meuh I used your solution for labelling the y-axis. It turned out that when I was using ```'~{\Symbol q}{1.1.}'``` the *dot* was not visible (printed outside the plot!). When I included a space at the end (```'~{\Symbol q}{1.1.} '```) it was visible again. Can you tell me why?

Comment: @amzon-ex This seems to be a bug in gnuplot and depends on which version you use. I tthink it is fixed in some version 5.

Comment: @meuh I'm using gp5.2.8, which seems like the latest version...

Comment: @amzon-ex Sorry, I'm sure it isn't designed to do that, but sadly I don't know why it does and cannot suggest any other workaround.